# Understanding glibc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glibc, shared-libraries

I'd like to distribute my program as a binary, not in source code form. I have two test systems: An older Linux (openSUSE 11.2 with glibc 2.10) and a recent one (LinuxMint 13 with glibc 2.15). Now when I compile my program on the LinuxMint system with glibc 2.15 and then try to start the binary on the openSUSE system with glibc 2.10 I get the following two errors:

```
./a.out: /lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./a.out)
./a.out: /lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by ./a.out)
```

What is confusing me here is this: Why do I get the "glibc 2.11 not found" error here as well? I would expect the program to require glibc 2.15 now because it has been compiled with glibc 2.15. Why is the program looking for glibc 2.11 as well? Does this mean that my program will run on both glibc versions, i.e. 2.15 AND 2.11? So it requires at least 2.11? Or will it require 2.15 in any case?

Another question: Is the assumption correct that glibc is upwards compatible but not downwards? E.g. is a program compiled with glibc 2.10 guaranteed to work flawlessly with any future version of glibc? If that is the case, what happens if a constant like PATH_MAX is changed in the future? Currently it is set to 4096 and I'm allocating my buffers for the realpath() POSIX function using the PATH_MAX constant. Now if this constant is raised to 8192 in the future, there could be problems because my program allocates only 4096 bytes. Or did I misunderstand something here?

Thanks for explanations!

Comment: try statically linking your code: `gcc -static mycode.c` ...

Comment: Also: there's too many questions in your question. You'll get better answers if you post just one clear question.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: You have to distribute sources if you do that!!!

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: That's not an option because then my program would fall under the GPL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Libc uses a symbol versioning. It's rather advanced wizardry, but basically each symbol is attached tag according to version where it appeared. If it's semantics changes, there are two versions, one for the old semantics with the version where it first appeared and another with the new semantics and the version where it appeared. The loader will only complain about symbols your program actually requests. Some of them happened to be introduced in 2.15 and some of them happened to be introduced in 2.11.

The whole point of this is to keep glibc backward compatible. It's really important, because there is a lot of packaged software, all of it is linked dynamically and recompiling all of it would take really long. There is also lot of software that does not have sources available and the old build of libc might not work with new kernel or new something else.

So yes, glibc is backward compatible. Just make sure you compile against the oldest version you need it to run with, because it is not (and can't be) forward compatible.

Ad PATH_MAX: If a change like that is done, glibc would simply export new versions of symbols that use the new value and old versions of symbols with suitable safegurads to work with code compiled against the old value. That's the main point of all that wizardry.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any method to find out what symbols of 2.15 it is referencing? I'd really be curious to find that out because I'm just using plain old C functions. Can't really imagine why it would need symbols from 2.15 for that....

Comment: @Andreas: I believe one of `ldd` or `objdump` will list the required symbols including their versions.

Comment: @Andreas: Some of the functions might have _changed_ between 2.10 and 2.15. Perhaps some constants, definition of some structure or something did. So the function, while source-compatible, would have different binary interface. Old and new version is provided, but when compiling you always get the newest definition available.

Comment: @JanHudec: _"So yes, glibc is backward compatible"_ - are there any official references? Unfortunately I am unable to find these...

Comment: @andreee, I believe it is kind of implied in the versioning. As long as the major so-version does not change, any shared library is expected to be backward compatible. And libc has been libc.so.6 ever since the ELF transition.